# Why is everything a background process?

Tags: python, windows-iot

I am new to RaspberryPi, I am using RaspberryPi 2 with windows 10 core, using visual studio 15 community for development. Under C# code template and python code template why is everything a background process? I need to interface 3 stepper motors with my Pi and also initiate them and other functions at clock tick(Keeping a track of date day and time) which I can't run in background it has to be the foreground (Main Task). Can anyone help out here, how can I achieve this? using background task or how can I go for a foreground task on my Pi. 
P.S: Any information would be helpful, also some information on interfacing stepper motors would be amazing!

Comment: I'm not a windows user, but I know the API allows for setting pseudo real-time priorities, which is probably more what you want; foreground tasks in windows just have a slightly boosted priority, but real-time ones can be higher (i.e., the foreground process is not necessarily the highest priority).  See, e.g., [SetPriorityClass()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686219(v=vs.85).aspx).  Hopefully python has some interface to that.

Comment: @goldilocks Thanks for the help. But the main issue was how can I use stepper motors and clock as a background process. It needs to run in the foreground. I am new to Raspberry pi but as on other windows devices a background process can only run after a certain time limit (15 minutes for phone and 30 for PC). I'll need some more help!

Comment: Interesting problem...

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft, for some odd reason, only provides the background template for IOT.  But you can create a Windows Universal Blank App Project to get the results you seek.